Cite specific theorem in revtex4-1
I want to use the command \cite[Theorem number]{citation_key} to get an output like [5, Theorem Number]. However, in revtex4-1 this is displayed as a reference number superscript followed by (Theorem number).  The \onlinecite[Theorem number]{citation_key} is no better, it writes the Theorem Number after the reference number, between commas.
Is there a nicer way of doing this? I want to submit to Journal of Mathematical Physics, I can't find any guidelines on how to do this in revtex.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Note that revtex4-1 is depreceated, you should move to revtex4-2. The class has a manual, have you checked which options it offers.
